# mutation inside a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, scope, mutation

n00b question here:

Suppose you call a function that updates a number or string like this

```
var x = "well";
var helloify = function(str){
  str += "hello"
};
```

I'd expect this behavior:

```
helloify(x);
console.log(x)
\\ "well hello"
```

But instead I get

```
\\ "well"
```

doesn't "+=" change the value of "x"? does this change only persist in the scope of the function but not in the global environment?

thanks!

--confused

Comment: "*doesn't "+=" change the value of "x"?*" Not in this case. It changes the value of `str`. But, `str` was only copying the value of `x`. The two variables are completely independent and unaware of each other.

Comment: Primitives are passed by value, it means that what you get into a function is actually a copy of the original value outside.

Answer (score 7):

When you call `helloify(x);` you pass the **value** of `x` (a string) not a *reference* to `x`.

`str += "hello"` modifies `str` and leaves `x` alone.

---

NB: Objects are only addressed by reference, so if `x` had been a reference to an object then you would have modified the single object addressed by both variables. Simple strings are not objects though.

Comment: This seems like a confusing way to explain what's going on.  Strings are immutable so `str += "hello"` creates a new string and assigns that new string to the `str` argument variable which has nothing to do with the string  which was originally passed in.  It would work the same as if one passed in an object instead of a string and assigned a new object to `str`.  Internally, `str` is probably essentially a pointer to the same string that `x` points to (not a reference, but a pointer).  Assigning to `str` then places a new string pointer in the `str` variable.

Comment: @MariusMucenicu - I don't know what magic you're looking for here.  [The spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation) just says that it applies the operator and then assigns the result back to the variable.  FYI, you can peruse the spec just as well as I can.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of how parameters are send, because of how strings are handled, and because of what the `+=` operator really does.

Parameters are sent by value, so the function doesn't get the string variable, it gets a copy of the reference to the string object.

Strings are immutable, which means that you will never change a string object<sup>1</sup>. When you alter a string, that will actually create a new string with the new value.

The `str += "hello"` is short for `str = str + "hello"`. This means that it will create a new string with the value `str + "hello"` and put the reference to that string object in the variable `str`.

As the parameter is not the variable that you sent into the function but a copy, assigning a new string to the parameter won't change the variable that you used in the function call.

---

<sup>1</sup> The Javascript engine might actually change a string object if it knows that the string will never be used any more, i.e. when it can safely do so while keeping the behaviour of immutable strings.